# Word for "truncate to size zero"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Is there a word for "truncate to size zero", preferably one which could be used and understood in the following way:

"...ing the file" := "truncating the file to zero bytes"?

RECAP: The best answers so far seem to be "empty the file", "zero the file size" and "truncate to (size|length) zero". In a suitable context, "truncate" has "truncate to (size|length) zero" as the default meaning (esp. since it's the commonest specific length to which files are truncated) but it's by no means the only one

Comment: "To truncate" means to cut down, usually assuming, I think, that something is left. Wouldn't "truncating a file to zero bytes" be the same as "**deleting** the file"?

Comment: It isn't. "...ing to size 0" affects only file size (perhaps truncate isn't the right word, ow. I could use it in this meaning already), delete affects its existence

Comment: Zero-size dummy files are quick patches used when one can't be bothered to rewrite the code. No formal definition is necessary. "Bring the size down to zero," "nullify the file's size," whatever. Anything will do. "Truncate" is very obviously wrong.

Comment: @Ricky There are plenty of situations where someone would truncate a file that have nothing to do with temporary files, and where no code was written. A quick google search will show that truncate is frequently used for this purpose.

Comment: @jimm101: I agree with you: it is a popular word, and it does sound sophisticated to some people. That said, truncating to zero only makes relativistic sense. The Latin word _trancare_ means "to lop off," not "to cut down."

Comment: @Silenus: There is [history behind the use of the word "truncate"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) in this context (do Ctrl+F "truncate").  We can't very well rename `O_TRUNC` without breaking lots of code.

Comment: When you truncate a file to zero (or some other size), what you're doing is setting the file's metadata size attribute to a value of zero. Nothing happens to the file data, except that it is no longer associated with its former metadata. If you know how to, you can re-associate the file with its metadata. 'Truncate' is a metaphor. What you're doing is "zeroing the file [size]".

Comment: `man fopen` uses "Truncate file to zero length" once explicitly and from then on just "truncate" for the same concept, the zero length thus being understood

Comment: Seems to me that you have several good words/terms there to pick from.

Comment: Or if all else fails just say "lop it off at the head".

Answer (score 11):

***empty*** the file, could be used. After all, one is left with an *empty* file.

There is Google evidence of usage for [empty the file](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22empty+the+file%22).

There is also Google evidence of usage for [clear the file](https://www.google.com.au/search?q="clear+the+file").

Answer (score 10):

*Truncate* is the correct word. *Truncating a file* means to [eliminate all the content](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/truncate-large-text-file-in-unix-linux/). The MySQL command for removing a table in database is [TRUNCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html), which I present as a related term that clearly indicates the "zero size" aspect.

EDIT:  Just to be clear, the "to size zero" is redundant.  Truncate means what you want to say here.

Comment: You are probably right that "truncate" is the best single word for it (but in general, "truncating a file" means [truncating it to a specific length](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Truncate_a_file), which may or may not be zero)

Comment: @jaam - the size defaults to zero if not specified.

Comment: @SomethingDark: that’s a default for certain programming languages, but not for English as spoken by most humans.  For me, *truncate* in a programming context certainly can include the case of truncating to length 0, but my default expectation would be a non-zero length.  Possibly there are some communities who would use it for 0 by default — I haven’t spent time around SQL professionals, for instance — but in the absence of other evidence, I somewhat doubt it.

Comment: In my experience, truncate to a length triggers more confusion than truncate to zero. Let's remember there's also a specific context here in terms of file length, so general usage in English is secondary at best. Programmers form a community where English is spoken among non-native talkers, so words tend to pick up nuanced meanings that don't always apply outside that domain.

Answer (score 2):

"Zeroing out" the file? Used to specify that a file has been deleted/shredded using an algorithm that sets all bits that were used to store the file to zeroes.

Comment: The question is looking for a word for reducing the file's *length* to zero bytes long, not overwriting the file with bytes of value zero. Also, "zeroing out" the file would generally imply filling it with zero-valued bytes without changing its size or deleting it from the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the word *diminish* could be used to mean reduce absolutely, to nothing.

> to become or to cause (something) to become less in size, importance, etc.

Mirriam Webster

So you could say, ***diminishing the file***.

Comment: Diminish reduces the size of the file, not necessarily to zero bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Truncating can be replaced with " Reducing " as " Reducing to a size zero"

Example: The file should be truncated to size zero or Reduced to a zero size. Both can be used preferably.

Answer (score 0):

Diminishing can also be used but the exact extent should be noted otherwise it will express indistinctly that what amount you want to diminish to.

Example: You should Diminish the cloth to a size zero.